# Serializing an object that contains a System.Drawing.Image to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-4.5

I have run into a bit of a problem and cannot seem to wrap my head around the solution...

I have an interface (and implemented class) that contains an image...

```
    Guid uid { get; set; }
    Image imageData1 { get; set; }
    string fileName { get; set; }
```

the image is stored in the DB as a byte[] getting it out is not an issue as I deserialize to a dynamic and then populate the object I want with that using a conversion function I wrote to convert byte[] to image.

the problem is the other direction...

```
string tmpJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( IclassOjbect );
```

this function serializes the class name of the image. but not the image data as a byte array.

I can take the image data and convert to a byte[] outside of the serialization but do not know how to inject that into the tmpJSON in place of the "image class name" without doing some dangerous string manipulation....

does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you add one more byte[] field to your object and exclude ([JsonIgnore])  image from serialization?

Comment: That's an option but not an enticing one, once serialized I use EF to save to the database and that change would trickle down significantly

Comment: Then I think custom JsonConverter is the way to go. Example - http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just found this on top of google, so I thought I might add an answer, even after all that time:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public Image Image { get; set; } = null;

public byte[] ImageAsByte
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Image != null)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                this.Image.Save(ms, this.Image.RawFormat);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(value))
            {
                this.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```